# gdb not debugging mingw32-g++ compiled code well, but works with g++

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, mingw32

I have a simple c++ program I'd like to debug with gdb. When I compile it with 
`g++ -g main.cpp -o main.exe`
I can use gdb just fine with the resulting executable. But when I use
`mingw32-g++ -g main.cpp -o main.exe`
gdb says things such as

> in ?? ()

and functionality is limited; I seem to be able to set break points and run the program, but stepping and such yields the message

> Cannot find bounds of current function

As I said, this only happens when compiling with the `mingw32-g++` executable, and not with the plain `g++` one.

Why is this, and how can I debug executables created with `migw32-g++`? Both executables run without issue.

**Extra info:**

- Am on Windows 7.
- g++ version: 4.8.2
- mingw32-g++ version: 4.8.1
- gdb version: 7.6.50.[lots of numbers]-cvs

If there's any other info I can provide to help find the issue, just let me know.

Comment: Why do you use the mingw32-g++ executable at all? And why it has a different version that g++?

Comment: THe simple truth is, it was the default executable in my code::blocks setup, and I've done a lot in it now. When trying to change to g++ and rebuilding the whole project, I get "cannot find -lSDL2" and similar errors, even tho all other settings are the exact same, so linker should have no problems finding them. Looking closer at the output, one notices the linker does actually go over the libraries I'm providing, outputtin something like "skipping incompatible [path to library] when looking for [library]. That seems even harder to fix so I was hoping someone could solve this instead.